# Serving assets using nginx, kubernetes and docker

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

There is a need to serve assets such as images/video/blobs that are going to be used in a website and a set of mobile apps. I am thinking of running following setup:

1. Run nginx in a docker container to serve assets
2. Run a side car container with a custom app which will pull these assets from a remote location and put in to a 'local storage'. Nginx gets assets from this local storage. Custom app will keep local storage up to date.

To run this setup I need to make sure that the pods that runs these two containers have a local storage which is accessible from both containers. To achieve this, I am thinking of restricting these pods to a set of nodes in the kubernetes cluster and provision local persisted volumes in these nodes. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

> To achieve this, I am thinking of restricting these pods to a set of nodes in the kubernetes cluster and provision local persisted volumes in these nodes.

Why go for a Persistent Volume when the Sidecar container can pull the assets at any time from the remote location. Create a volume with [EmptyDirVolumeSource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.12/#emptydirvolumesource-v1-core) and mount it on both the containers in the Pod. The Sidecar container has Write permissions on the volume and the main container has a Read permission.

Comment: asset store would be huge and asking the side car container to pull all these when ever kuberntes re-schedule the pod is going to take lot of time.

Comment: In this case then HostPathVolumeSource https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.12/#hostpathvolumesource-v1-core could be used. When the pod is restricted to a few nodes, then it doesn't really provide high availability and is also not much scalable.

Comment: I agree, but I don't see any other alternative. These pods can scale in restricted set of nodes at-least. I will also check your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of your issue, it looks like distributed file systems might be what you are looking for.

For example **CephFS** and **Glusterfs** are supported in Kubernetes ( [Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/), [PersistentVolumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes) ) and have a good set of capabilities like concurrent access ( *both* ) and PVC expanding ( *Glusterfs* ):

> #### [cephfs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#cephfs)
>
> A cephfs volume allows an existing CephFS volume to be mounted into your Pod. Unlike emptyDir, which is erased when a Pod is
>   removed, the contents of a cephfs volume are preserved and the volume
>   is merely unmounted. This means that a CephFS volume can be
>   pre-populated with data, and that data can be “handed off” between
>   Pods. CephFS can be mounted by multiple writers simultaneously.
>
> Important: You must have your own Ceph server running with the share
>   exported before you can use it.
>
> See the CephFS [example](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/cephfs/) for more details.
>
> #### [glusterfs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#cephfs)
>
> A glusterfs volume allows a Glusterfs (an open source networked filesystem) volume to be mounted into your Pod.
>   Unlike emptyDir, which is erased when a Pod is removed, the contents
>   of a glusterfs volume are preserved and the volume is merely
>   unmounted. This means that a glusterfs volume can be pre-populated
>   with data, and that data can be “handed off” between Pods. GlusterFS
>   can be mounted by multiple writers simultaneously.
>
> Important: You must have your own GlusterFS installation running
>   before you can use it.
>
> See the [GlusterFS](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/cephfs/) example for more details.

For more information about these topics check out the following links:

- [Using Existing Ceph Cluster for Kubernetes Persistent Storage](https://akomljen.com/using-existing-ceph-cluster-for-kubernetes-persistent-storage/)
- [GlusterFS Native Storage Service for Kubernetes](https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes)
- [TWO DAYS OF PAIN OR HOW I DEPLOYED GLUSTERFS CLUSTER TO KUBERNETES](https://blog.lwolf.org/post/how-i-deployed-glusterfs-cluster-to-kubernetes/)